# Container registry not listed when creating service connection

Tags: azure-devops

I have created a Azure Container Registry in my Azure subscription and wanted to use Azure Devops to build and push my containers. I am trying to create a service connection however when selecting my subscription the screen states "No registries found"

I also tried to create a pipeline using the Docker (Build and push an image to ACR) and this screen also cannot find my registry.

The registry exists and was created as a "Basic" SKU. I have tried other SKUs as well with no luck.

Any ideas of what I can do to be able to select my registry in Devops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be caused by an expired token. Generally, we can try below ways to get it work (force refresh the token).

- Go to [Azure DevOps user profile page](https://aex.dev.azure.com/me) and switch to another directory, and then switch it back again. During the operation, it will force you to sign out and sign in again. Thus, it will refresh the token from AAD. If you have multiple directories here, then please do the same actions one by one, and then switch it back to the original directory (AAD) which you Azure DevOps organization needs to be backed to. After that try it again
- Go to the affected ACR from Azure portal, then **disable** and **re-enable** admin account. (Click **Update** -> Enable/Disable the “**Admin user**” -> Save -> Disable/Enable the “**Admin user**”  again -> **Save**). After that refresh the DevOps page and check if it works now.
  [image]

Comment: Refreshing the token solved the issue

Comment: I have the same issue, tried it both ways multiple times. Still don't see anything in the docker task.

Comment: The 2nd way disable/re-enable admin user worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Disabling and re-enabling the admin account worked for me...  I was scratching my head over this for the last couple of days, so thanks @Andy-Li-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same thing, just had to wait about an hour for the container registry to be recognized :/